# Initialise a database with SpatiaLite 4.3

Tags: spatialite

I am starting to work with SpatiaLite 4.3 in an empty database. SpatiaLite requires a number of meta-data tables, where it stores information about geometry fields. For previous versions there are SQL scripts that create and initialise these tables; for instance, [the release page for version 2.3](https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.3/) lists a script named `init_spatialite-2.3.sql`.

I have not been able to find a similar script for version 4.3. Is the database initialised differently in this version?

Comment: Use InitSpatialMetadata http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

Comment: @user30184 Would you like to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With current SpatiaLite versions the spatial metadata tables are created with SQL function `InitSpatialMetadata()`. The usage is documented in http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html

> Creates the geometry_columns and spatial_ref_sys metadata tables the 
>   return type is Integer, with a return value of 1 for TRUE or 0 for 
>   FALSE
>
> - if the optional argument transaction is set to TRUE the whole operation will be handled as a single Transaction (faster): the >
>     default setting is transaction=FALSE (slower, but safer).
> - if the optional argument mode is not specified then any possible ESPG SRID definition will be inserted into the spatial_ref_sys table.
> - if the mode arg 'WGS84' (alias 'WGS84_ONLY') is specified, then only WGS84-related EPSG SRIDs will be inserted
> - if the mode arg 'NONE' (alias 'EMPTY') is specified, no EPSG SRID will be inserted at all

Single transaction is much faster, about 1 second vs. one minute.

```
select InitSpatialMetadata(1);
```

If the size of the database is critical then using mode WGS84 or NONE will save about 5 megabytes but then you may need to insert the SRID definitions that you need later with `InsertEpsgSrid`.